# mongodb (pymongo) `update` didn't work

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, nosql

Let's say I want to do some simple `update` operations on document `e` like this :

```
print 'Updating:',e['title'],e['_id']
jp.update(e,{'$set':{'sensesJa':sensesJa,'last':'#pushFormsAndSetNewAtt'},
            '$push':{'forms':{'$each':forms_to_push}}})
```

It did print 'Updating: ...', but the document didn't get updated. Any idea?

***Update: add gist:***
https://gist.github.com/actor2019/5876903#file-clip-mongodb-pymongo-update-didnt-work-py-L36

Comment: AFAIK, there is no parameter called `safe` in `update` function http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update

Comment: Thanks thefourtheye. It didn't work either with or without `safe`.

Comment: Can you please give a sample document which you are trying to update?

Comment: Nothing special.. {
    _id: "XXX_1150620",
    ps: {},
    senses: [],
    pt: 0,
    title: "XXX",
    forms: [
    ]
}

Comment: What exactly *is* `jp`? Since you print updating before the call so are you sure you are not suffering from an error in the code? Also what does `e` look like and what document should it update, can you show us from the terminal? Also what are the other vars?

Comment: Does `e` match anything?  `print jp.find(e).count()`

Comment: If I changed `jp.update(e,{})` to `jp.update({'_id':e['_id']},{...})`, it worked.  `jp.find(e).count()` prints 0 ... No way... e was got via some shallow copy from the results of `jp.find()` just before this update operation.(`e` means entry) let's say we have some candidate entries `candidate_es= list(jp.find({'title':'someTitle'}))` then, `for ie in candidate_es`: `do some if-else and  get the correct_e`, finally let `e=correct_e`. I tried to print `p.find(correct_e).count()`, it turned out sometimes `1` sometimes `0`... I'm confused, since I didn't change the `e` or the `correct_e` at all.

Comment: update gist: https://gist.github.com/actor2019/5876903#file-clip-mongodb-pymongo-update-didnt-work-py-L36

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query part of your update isn't matching any documents, so nothing is matched to be updated.

As you know the `_id` then querying against just `e["_id"]` will ensure your query is targeted correctly.

```
jp.update(e['_id'], {'$set':{'sensesJa':sensesJa,'last':'#pushFormsAndSetNewAtt'},
                     '$push':{'forms':{'$each':forms_to_push}}})
```

### Update

Querying by a whole document is fine **and** as long as there is a match it will update.  Here is an example of querying and finding a document:

```
from pymongo import *
client = MongoClient()
coll = client.test.test

coll.save({'_id': 1, 'hello': 'world'})
e = coll.find_one()

print(e)
coll.find(e).count()
```

The output is **1** because it matches one document.  The only time that would fail is if I changed `e` or something (another process) removed `e` between me finding it the first time and then the second.

Comment: Thanks. But I want to find out why nothing matched while `jp.update(e,{})`, since e was just a shallow copy of one of the results of `jp.find()` and I didn't touch it at all.

Comment: Well does `jp.find(e)` not return anything?  If not, the document has changed (by another process?) or been deleted.

Comment: No... I didn't change the `e` at all, and `e` could still be correctly accessed just before the update operation. I thought that, if I `update` a document, pymongo would try to find out if the document (or  generally a dict) contains an `_id` and use the _id to update the corresponding document. But, it seems that it do it in a different way, perhaps just do what `find` and `find_one` do to locate the document and update it. Anyway, I don't know why I can't find `e`... :)

Comment: The find part matches on the whole document - if it doesnt match then the document doesn't exist in that database / collection.  

There is some sort of logic error happening in you app code, but if you can show some code proving that isn't the case then please do!  

Also, you do not need to do a separate `find` query then `update`, the `query` part of update works *exactly* the same as in `find`.

Comment: Check this: https://gist.github.com/actor2019/5876903#file-clip-mongodb-pymongo-update-didnt-work-py-L36 (in line 15, I should use for `ie` in es: ... )